# reconnect an activemq subscriber over stomp protocol written in ruby if activemq broker goes down

Tags: ruby, activemq-classic, stomp

I have an activemq subscriber written in ruby i want it to reconnect back automatically if activemq broker goes down, when it comes up. I tried adding failover protocol and it does work for one time but not after that.